# How can I turn this code into a repeatable function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have the following code and set of functions (more easily read in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5PLfM/)).

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Example</title>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      // Returns the max Y value in our data list
      function getMaxY() {
         var max = 0;

         for(var i = 0; i < data.values.length; i++) {
            if(data.values[i].Y > max) {
               max = data.values[i].Y;
            }
         }

         max += 10 - max % 10;
         return max;
      }

      // Return the x pixel for a graph point
      function getXPixel(val) {
         return((graph.width() - xPadding) / data.values.length) * val + (xPadding * 1.5);
      }

      // Return the y pixel for a graph point
      function getYPixel(val) {
         return graph.height() - (((graph.height() - yPadding) / getMaxY()) * val) - yPadding + 10;
      }

      // Image
      draw_image = function(path, c) {
        var img;
        img = new Image();
        img.src = path;
        return img.onload = function() {
          return c.drawImage(img, getXPixel(data.values.length - 1) - 2, getYPixel(data.values.slice(-1)[0].Y + 20), 28, 28);
        };
      };

      var graph;
      var xPadding = -50;
      var yPadding = 20;
      var data = {values:[{X:"1",Y:12},{X:"2",Y:28},{X:"3",Y:58},{X:"4",Y:34},{X:"5",Y:40},{X:"6",Y:45},{X:"7",Y:40},{X:"8",Y:40},{X:"9",Y:40},{X:"13",Y:40},{X:"14",Y:60},{X:"15",Y:32},{X:"16",Y:40},{X:"17",Y:26},{X:"18",Y:40},{X:"19",Y:30},{X:"20",Y:35}]}

      $(document).ready(function() {

         graph = $('canvas');

         var c = graph[0].getContext('2d');

         c.lineWidth = 5;
         c.strokeStyle = '#fff';
         c.shadowColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.13)";
         c.shadowOffsetX = 0;
         c.shadowOffsetY = 1;

         // Draw the line graph
         c.beginPath();
         c.moveTo(getXPixel(0), getYPixel(data.values[0].Y));
         for(var i = 1; i < data.values.length; i++) {
            c.lineTo(getXPixel(i), getYPixel(data.values[i].Y));
         }
         c.stroke();

         //Draw the ending icon
         draw_image("/images/icon.png", c);
      });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <section class="question_listing">
      <article data-question-id="1">
         <canvas width="200" height="70"></canvas>
      </article>
      <article data-question-id="2">
         <canvas width="200" height="70"></canvas>
      </article>
   </section>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5PLfM/), the chart is only getting drawn on the first occurrence of the `canvas` (rightly so).

But what I need help doing is turning this into something that can be repeated.

Ideally, I could do something like `$('article canvas').littleChart();` and have it apply to all occurrences of that selector.

Just kind of lost at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery statement will return all canvases on the page. You'll just have to loop through each of them and apply what you already have.

Put a loop around the code in your document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    graph = $('canvas');

    for (var ii=0; ii < graph.length; ii++) {

        var c = graph[ii].getContext('2d');

        c.lineWidth = 5;
        c.strokeStyle = '#fff';
        c.shadowColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.13)";
        c.shadowOffsetX = 0;
        c.shadowOffsetY = 1;

        // Draw the line graph
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(getXPixel(0),getYPixel(data.values[0].Y));
        for(var i = 1; i < data.values.length; i++) {
            c.lineTo(getXPixel(i), getYPixel(data.values[i].Y));
        }
        c.stroke();

        //Draw the ending icon
        draw_image("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon4.png", c);
    }
});
```

And that should do the trick. You might want to rename 'graph' with something more descriptive like canvasList.